# binding text box from listbox

Tags: wpf, binding, listbox

I am new in wpf
I am trying to bind listbox from datagrid the code is like this

```
DataGrid dataGrid = control as DataGrid;      
Columnslst.ItemsSource = dataGrid.Columns;      
Columnslst.DisplayMemberPath = "Header";
```

now i wont to bind text box from the Columnslst listbox in xaml

```
<TextBox Name="txtGridHeader" Margin="2" Text="{Binding ElementName=Columnslst, Path=SelectedItem.content}" ></TextBox>
```

but it does not work

why ???

what can i do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the c# code, each item in the DataSource if of `DataGridColumn` type and one of its properties is `Header`, just like you've set in `DisplayMemberPath`.

In the `SelectedItem` you should have direct access to one of those objects (if any of them is selected),  so so it's still of `DataGridColumn` type. Just try to use this line in xaml:

```
<TextBox Name="txtGridHeader" Margin="2" Text="{Binding ElementName=Columnslst, Path=SelectedItem.Header}" ></TextBox>
```

Let me know if it worked for you.